# Prefix or part of URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, web, seo

I will develop tourist site about region. This site will consist of parts about cities in this region. Parts have same design and features. Home page of site will has information from all parts about all cities.

How do I design path structure of site? I saw that some sites for same purpose use prefixes like:

`city.region.com`

But another sites just add part to URL:

`region.com/city`

What is the best solution? (from SEO and Rails development points of view)

Answer (score 1):

When you add a prefix to the site name, that is considered a subdomain. Subdomains are considered separate website so If SEO is a goal of yours, you will have a higher chance of showing up multiple times for a search.

On the other hand, I consider it a lot easier to add to the URL. This is the approach I would take, avoiding any premature optimization.

Source : http://www.ameravant.com/article/3398-subdomains-and-seo-pros-and-cons-of-subdomains-vs-subdirectories